Infer generic type from zod schema
I have a generic Message<T extends MessageBody> type, and I would like to replace it with a zod schema and a type inferred from that schema. But how do I infer a generic type?
I have something like this:
type MessageBody = string | object

type Message<T extends MessageBody> = {
  body: T;
}

type SpecificBody = {
  specific: string
}

const message: Message<SpecificBody>

I replaced this with the following zod schema and type inference:
const MessageBodySchema = z.union([
  z.string(),
  z.object({}),
  z.undefined()
])

const MessageSchema = z.object({
  body: MessageBodySchema
})

type Message = z.infer<typeof MessageSchema>

Now I have a schema to validate messages with. But how can I use Message like Message<SpecificBody>?

You might be over-doing the Zod where it is not needed
const MessageBodySchema = z.union([
  z.string(),
  z.object({}),
  z.undefined()
])

// Does not need to be a ZodType
type Message<Schema extends z.ZodSchema> = {
  body: z.output<Schema>
}

const message: Message<typeof MessageBodySchema> = {
  body: ['foo', undefined, {}]
}

edit:
To still be able to use the MessageSchema as a validator you could have a look at something like
// Generic function which allows you to pass a body to your zod object
const MessageSchemaBuilder = <T extends Schema>(schema: T) => z.object({
  body: schema
})

// Use the builder for your schema, use the schema for validation
const MessageSchema = MessageSchemaBuilder(MessageBodySchema)

type Message = z.infer<ReturnType<typeof MessageSchemaBuilder<typeof MessageBodySchema>>>
// or
type Message = z.infer<typeof MessageSchema>


Now there is no no MessageSchema to validate messages with. How to validate messages in this setup?

See the update, perhaps this could help you
